# ctypes struct containing arrays and manipulating

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I'm trying to use ctypes in my python code `test.py`to pass the array to `test.c` and do some calculation and bring the result to python code.

Here is 'test.c'

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "test.h"

void test(int N, complex *v){
    int k;
    for(k=0; k<N; k++){
        v[k].Re = v[k].Re + 1;
        v[k].Im = v[k].Im + 1;    
        printf("%d %f %f\n", k, v[k].Re, v[k].Im);
    }
}
```

v is the structed array defined in `test.h`

```
typedef struct{float Re; float Im;} complex;
```

From Python I can do something like this

```
import numpy as np
from ctypes import cdll
from ctypes import *

class complex(Structure):
    _fields_ = (('Re', POINTER(c_float)),
                ('Im', POINTER(c_float)))

    def __init__(self, I, Q, lenIQ):
        array_type = c_float * lenIQ
        self.Re = array_type(*I)
        self.Im = array_type(*Q)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Complex({self.Re}, {self.Im})'

cgmap = cdll.LoadLibrary('./test.dll')
test = cgmap.test
test.argtypes = (c_int, complex)
I = [2,2,3,4]
Q = [5,6,7,8]
lenIQ = len(I)

myarray = complex(I, Q, lenIQ)
test(c_int(lenIQ), myarray)
print(myarray)
print(myarray[0])
```

But when I execute `test.py`, then :

```
0 4284182633119744.000000 1.000000
1 4585659272527872.000000 1.000000
2 3.983704 1.000000
3 3.983746 1.000000
Complex(<__main__.LP_c_float object at 0x0000029959825A48>, <__main__.LP_c_float object at 0x0000029959825A48>)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 28, in <module>
    print(myarray[0])
TypeError: 'complex' object does not support indexing
```

Is there anyway to solve without modifying `test.c`? Any help would be appreciated ;)

Comment: ah I forgot to include that line. I edited the question!

Comment: Where's in the code `print(myarray[0])`? Also, why pointers inside the structure? https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#structures-and-unions. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/65743183/4788546, as this seems kind of a duplicate.

Comment: When I edit the complex class like this :
    class complex(Structure):
        _fields_ = (('Re', (c_float)),
                    ('Im', (c_float)))
    (skip)
I get the message saying : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 24, in <module>
    myarray = complex(I, Q, lenIQ)
  File "test.py", line 11, in __init__
    self.Re = array_type(*I)
TypeError: incompatible types, c_float_Array_4 instance instead of c_float instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are mixing up between creating a struct, creating an array of struct, and creating a pointer to an array of struct, those are 3 different operations, i have commented the code for clarity.

```py
import numpy as np
from ctypes import cdll
from ctypes import *

class complex(Structure):  # struct with two floats
    _fields_ = (('Re', c_float),
                ('Im', c_float))

    def __init__(self, I_val, Q_val):
        self.Re = I_val
        self.Im = Q_val

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Complex({self.Re}, {self.Im})'

I = [2,2,3,4]
Q = [5,6,7,8]
lenIQ = len(I)
my_array_type = complex*lenIQ  # create the type of array (complex[])
my_array = my_array_type()  # create the array (complex my_array[4])

for i in range(len(I)):
    my_array[i] = complex(I[i],Q[i])  # fill each individual object in the array

# next line is equivalent to "complex* pointer_to_array = (complex*)(my_array);"
pointer_to_array = cast(my_array, POINTER(complex))  # create the pointer to the first element of the array (complex*)

print(my_array)  # prints type of my_array
print(my_array[0])  # equivalent to c's my_array[0]
print(pointer_to_array[0])  # equivalent to c's pointer_to_array[0]
```

```
<__main__.complex_Array_4 object at 0x000002195A9B8C40>
Complex(2.0, 5.0)
Complex(2.0, 5.0)
```

now for calling

```py
cgmap = cdll.LoadLibrary('./test.dll')
test = cgmap.test
test.argtypes = (c_int, POINTER(complex))
test.restype  = None
test(c_int(lenIQ), pointer_to_array)
```

Comment: You saved my life You are a GOD... I want to upvote your answer but my reputation falls short...

Comment: @DanaKim if this answers your question please accept the answer (click the true sign left of the answer)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your types match.  The structure contains `c_float` not `POINTER(c_float)` to match the C definition.  The `.argtypes` are `c_int` and `POINTER(Complex)`.

`ctypes` can initialize the structure and arrays without a lot of extra work:

**test.c**

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
#   define API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#   define API
#endif

typedef struct { float Re; float Im; } complex;

API void test(int N, complex *v) {
    int k;
    for(k = 0; k < N; ++k) {
        v[k].Re = v[k].Re + 1;
        v[k].Im = v[k].Im + 1;
        printf("%d %f %f\n", k, v[k].Re, v[k].Im);
    }
}
```

**test.py**

```py
import ctypes as ct

class Complex(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = (('Re', ct.c_float),  # not POINTER(c_float)
                ('Im', ct.c_float))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Complex({self.Re:g}{self.Im:+g}j)'

    @staticmethod
    def array(reals, imags):
        '''Helper method to create Complex arrays.
        '''
        return (Complex * len(reals))(*zip(reals, imags))

I = [2,2,3,4]
Q = [5,6,7,8]

arr = Complex.array(I, Q)
print(list(arr)) # easy way to display the contents when __repr__ is defined.

dll = ct.CDLL('./test')
dll.test.argtypes = ct.c_int, ct.POINTER(Complex)
dll.test.restype = None

dll.test(len(arr), arr)
```

Output:

```
[Complex(2+5j), Complex(2+6j), Complex(3+7j), Complex(4+8j)]
0 3.000000 6.000000
1 3.000000 7.000000
2 4.000000 8.000000
3 5.000000 9.000000
```